# Trigger azure function on user registration in b2c

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I want to trigger a function when a user registers in my azure AD B2C. But I can't find any examples on this. Is the user added to any queue or stored in any table? Or do I need to look at the respons back when the user clicks the "register" button in my app?

I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi#create-an-azure-ad-b2c-directory) to create my B2C. What I want is to eg. send a welcome mail.

Comment: B2C gives you `newUser: true` in the claims if you configure it to include it. Maybe you could receive that in your app and send the email from there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Azure AD B2C does not have any support for custom emails events or custom triggers through its built-in policies.

However, you can use Azure AD B2C [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) to [call out to a REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom) that sends an email as part of the authentication flow. You can easily implement this REST API using an [Http Triggered Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook).

Check out the sample code for such Azure function in the sample [SendMailWebHook function](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/AzureFunctionsSamples/SendMailWebHook).

You can also request support for custom email events in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c)

Comment: i tried to understand this but ended up with those xml files and referencing errors to something and so on... :( 
I just want to trigger an azure function when a user signs up or logs in.. are there any tutorials on this? (i already have a working built-in sign_in_up poilcy i want to modify)