# Is there an event from Azure Active Directory that the Event Grid can respond to?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

My demo app uses Azure AD B2C. Since it's a B2C, new users can create their own account. When a new user joins, I want:

1. to event grid to start a Logic app
2. the logic app will grab some of the data update the **CosmosDb** containers
3. send an email to the new user
4. deliver a message that any subscriber can read

I'm stuck in the beginning because I can't find anything that it's related to Azure Active Directory. I can't find a tutorial or any information related to tha.

[image]

My question is to know whether event grid can even be used to react to users being created in Azure AD?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this trigger can implement your requirement. As we can see it requires us to choose `Resource Type`, `Resource Name`... But users do not belong to resources, resources refer to storage, VM, keyvault and so on.

So for your question about

> whether event grid can even be used to react to users being created in Azure AD

I think it can't be used to react to users being created in Azure AD.

Comment: According to the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962303/trigger-azure-function-on-user-registration-in-b2c, there's no way that a Logic App can react directly to B2C event. The way to go is to implement `Custom policies` then have a function that can trigger a `Logic App`.